# Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred. events=0x8

Tags: android, memory

So, I was testing my app out on various devices, and on some with less memory, it decides to crash after playing for a while. I think I have a memory leak somewhere, but that isn't the issue.

When it dies, it doesn't throw any exceptions, this is what the logcat gave me:

```
07-16 14:05:55.424  1318  1318 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000  cmp=org.waldev.platformer/.Menu } from pid 4631
07-16 14:05:56.213  1318  1349 I ActivityManager: Displayed org.waldev.platformer/.Menu: +613ms
07-16 14:05:58.252  1318  1509 I ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { cmp=org.waldev.platformer/.Platformer } from pid 4623
07-16 14:05:58.510  1220  1316 I ExtendFileSource:  filename = /data/app/org.waldev.platformer-1.apk
07-16 14:05:58.533  1220 10962 I ExtendFileSource:  filename = /data/app/org.waldev.platformer-1.apk
07-16 14:05:58.549  1220  7923 I ExtendFileSource:  filename = /data/app/org.waldev.platformer-1.apk
07-16 14:05:58.557  1220  1220 I ExtendFileSource:  filename = /data/app/org.waldev.platformer-1.apk
07-16 14:05:58.783  1318  1349 I ActivityManager: Resumed Activity:  org.waldev.platformer/.Menu totalTime: 3361 ms
07-16 14:05:58.783  1318  1349 I ActivityManager: Displayed org.waldev.platformer/.Platformer: +496ms
07-16 14:05:59.682  1220  1220 I ExtendFileSource:  filename = /data/app/org.waldev.platformer-1.apk
07-16 14:08:04.619  1220 10961 I ExtendFileSource:  filename = /data/app/org.waldev.platformer-1.apk
07-16 14:09:56.283  1318  1551 I ActivityManager: Process org.waldev.platformer (pid 4623) has died.
07-16 14:09:56.369  1318  1351 E InputDispatcher: channel '405409f8 org.waldev.platformer/org.waldev.platformer.Menu (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
07-16 14:09:56.369  1318  1351 E InputDispatcher: channel '405409f8 org.waldev.platformer/org.waldev.platformer.Menu (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
07-16 14:09:56.416  1318  6514 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{40576908 org.waldev.platformer/org.waldev.platformer.Menu paused=false}
07-16 14:09:56.557  1318  1537 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{405409f8 org.waldev.platformer/org.waldev.platformer.Menu paused=false}
07-16 14:09:56.572  1318  2103 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{409f0b80 org.waldev.platformer/org.waldev.platformer.Menu paused=false}
07-16 14:09:56.580  1318  1464 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{40543cf0 org.waldev.platformer/org.waldev.platformer.Menu paused=false}
07-16 14:09:56.603  1318  1509 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{4090ec68 org.waldev.platformer/org.waldev.platformer.Platformer paused=false}
07-16 14:09:56.853  1318  1551 I ActivityManager: Start proc org.waldev.platformer for activity org.waldev.platformer/.Menu: pid=5332 uid=10103 gids={1015}
07-16 14:09:58.291  1318  1349 I ActivityManager: Displayed org.waldev.platformer/.Menu: +1s677ms
```

It just seems like it decided to destroy my process without it ever telling me why. I looked around to see what causes android to do this, but I didn't see anything.

I saw the other questions about this on here, but none of them seemed to really answer why it was doing it, and that's more of what I am looking for. Does anyone know?

Comment: Ever make any progress on this issue? I'm investigating the same thing this morning and finding what you mentioned - lots of people asking this question and very few answers.